# ¿Qué significado tiene y cómo se emplea la palabra "disque"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

He visto algunos vídeos y frases en internet en donde se utiliza la palabra ***disque***, no sé si sea como una contracción de "dice que" o tenga algún significado diferente.

Ejemplo:

> Hace 3 semanas **disque** empezó a trabajar.

¿Alguien pudiera comentar sobre ello?

Comment: Could it be the subjunctive of _discar_? Perhaps you could give us some examples of where yo found it?

Comment: @mdewey I just added an example

Comment: [_dizque_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E1uS9B2), con Z, existe y quiere decir _al parecer, presuntamente_ en Hispanoamérica. Parece el caso, ¿encaja con lo que has venido oyendo?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser *dizque* como dice @fedorqui. ¿Sabes de qué países o regiones provenían esos videos y frases?

Comment: @fedorqui lo vi así mismo escrito de un latino que vive en USA, lo he escuchado también de varios latinos que viven en USA, no tengo idea de donde venga el término.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Dizque*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E1uS9B2), con Z, existe en el DLE: *dice que* -> *dicque* -> *dizque* para incorporar el sonido /z/ de *dice*.

> [**dizque**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E1uS9B2)
>   `De dice que.`
>
> 1. m. Dicho, murmuración, reparo. U. m. en pl.
>   2. adv. Am. Al parecer, presuntamente.

El Diccionario de americanismos también lo recoge:

> [**dizque**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=zeHexHNEJx0AfthwRV7)
>   `(Sínc. de dice que)`
>
> I.    1.  adv. Mx, Gu, Ho, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, PR, Co, Ve, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ar, Ur; Ch, p.u. Al parecer, presuntamente. pop + cult → espon. (diz que; quizque).
>   2.  adj. Bo; Mx, CR, Pe, pop. Referido a persona o cosa, presunta o pretendida. (diz que; quizque).
>   3.  m. pl. Bo. Habladurías, murmuraciones. pop + cult → espon.
>
> ●
>   a. ǁ    ~. fórm. Bo; Pe, p.u. Se usa para introducir un relato, un cuento o cualquier tipo de anécdota.
>
> □
>   a. ǁ    ~s y conques. loc. sust. Bo:E. Habladurías, murmuraciones. pop + cult → espon.
>   Es decir que quiere decir *al parecer, presuntamente* en Hispanoamérica.

En todo caso, siempre escrito con *z* y no con *s* (el error intuyo que será porque se menciona en alguna zona hispanhablante donde no se distingue *z* de *s* en el habla).

Por tanto, la frase:

> Hace 3 semanas disque empezó a trabajar.

Vendría a ser algo así como:

> Parece que empezó a trabajar hace 3 semanas.

Y el *dizque* se utiliza para reflejar realidades de las que no estamos del todo seguros.

Answer (score 3):

[Asihablamos.com](https://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/dizque) tiene **dizque** como término usado en Colombia, pero se usa igual en México:

> Palabra utilizada para fingir que hay acontecimientos importantes.
>   *Ese Byron se fue dizque a jugar fútbol*.

En mi experiencia, *dizque* refleja cierta sospecha o duda.  Byron dijo que iba a jugar fútbol, pero sospecho que iba a hacer otra cosa.  (No sé necesariamente que fue mentira.)

Sinónimos: supuestamente; según dijo.

Answer (score 3):

diSque con S lo usamos en Galicia (Noroesteste de España) dis es decir  en gallego, y disque lo usamos para referirnos a que a llegado a nuestros oídos pero sin querer decir mediante quien ( si es que existe y no es invención de uno mismo claro ). Como una unión de dicen que... tenemos otra que es seica, que viene a ser lo mismo solo que del verbo saber (sei). No sé si tendrá que ver si viajo a America o ahí nació de otra forma. Un saludo 
https://academia.gal/dicionario/-/termo/disque